# C# Put Static Class Inside Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, static

I was unclear in an earlier question I ask so I will try to be more explicit.

Is there a way to put a static class inside of a dictionary so that its functions can be called? If this is not possible, what is the best alternative that doesn't involve using instances that you can suggest?

Here is how I would like to use it:

```
static class MyStatic : IInterface
{
    static void Do(){}
}

static class MyStatic2 : IInterface
{
    static void Do(){}
}

class StaticMap
{
    static Dictionary<Type,IInterface.class> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type,IInterface.class>
    {
        {Type.1, MyStatic}
        {Type.2, MyStatic2}
    };
}

// Client Code

class ClientCode
{
    void Start()
    {
        StaticMap.dictionary[Type.1].Do();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using a static class.  This is what instances are for.

Comment: "in an earlier question" - please link other questions you mention. Or, in this particular case, it sounds like the best course of action would be to improve your earlier question rather than ask a new one.

Comment: I do think it would be a helpful feature at times, but unfortunately, interfaces cannot be implemented by static members in C#.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: I think that is a very restricted way of seeing things - one might call it C#-tunnel-vision. It would not inherently "make sense to put instances (...) in the dictionary", that's simply the only thing that is possible in C#. What would "make sense" (i.e. without taking into account language-specific restrictions) is not necessarily the same. In fact, I think a good counter-question would be "Why should the classes *not* be static?" If there is never going to be any second instance with a distinct state from the first, what's the point of creating an instance at all?

Comment: I agree with O.R. Mapper - Utility/helper classes that never get recycled should always be static. You're wasting valuable memory creating instances of something that could inherently exist.

Comment: @BrandonMiller if the static class just exposes static methods (and does not keep state) there is no memory difference between a static and non-static class.  If there _is_ state, a singleton would effectively solve that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Earlier question was deleted a while ago. Regarding interface restriction I dont even need the interface. Even if I could just map to the static function itself it would be fine but all my research and attempts has not worked.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy I already do things with instances, but the instance is useless because there is no state to maintain. I dont need the object or its state, I just need the function. I would love if it was possible to map a type directly to a static function

Comment: Since you're interested in functions, not objects or instances then perhaps it would make sense to modify your question accordingly. It specifies "static classes" but it doesn't sound like you care about those either. You don't want to put static classes in a dictionary - you want to put methods in a dictionary.

Comment: Either would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

There are some fundamental reasons why you can't do that directly:

- Static method calls are bound at compile-time
- Static calls are not inherited - they are tied to the class that defines them
- There is no implicit base type (and therefore no polymorphism) between static methods, even if the name, inputs, and outputs are all the same

Since your signature is the same for every static method, you could store a `Action` in the dictionary instead:

```
static Dictionary<Type,Action> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type,Action>
{
    {Type.1, MyStatic.Do}
    {Type.2, MyStatic2.Do}
};
```

then you can call the `Action` directly:

```
void Start()
{
    StaticMap.dictionary[Type.1]();
}
```

It's slightly repetetive because you have to specify the method name in the dictionary as well, but it's type safe.

Comment: Yes this could work, but the problem is basically I have all these resolver classes. They each have 3 methods and they are all static. By storing the methods, I need to have a dictionary per method where as I would have preferred just a dictionary to all the statics and calling methods as I need them. I guess the only way out of this will be to use instances. But I appreciate the insight.

Comment: You could make it a dictionary of `Type, (Action Method1, Action Method2, Action Method3)`. Then you call it like `dict[type].Method1()`. All the mapping you'll have to do manually show that there's something weird about this approach though. You may not need instances but that's probably the most elegant solution here. Also way faster than resorting to delegates.

Answer (score 2):

A key question is whether you want to call a single method on each type or whether you need to call multiple methods belonging to each type.

If it's just a single method, then what D Stanley suggested is the answer. If you store a number of `Action`s, each representing a method with the same signature on a different static class, then you're accomplishing what you said.

However that raises a question - why the constraint that each method must belong to a separate static class? This approach would work just as well if some or all of the methods belonged to the same class.

If you need to call more than one method from each class then an `Action` no longer works. You'd have to store collections of `Action`, which a) means class instances, and b) is a lot more complicated than just using interfaces and class instances.

One way to manage instances is by using a dependency injection container to create class instances for you. Using that approach, you can create non-static classes without having to go through the hassle of explicitly making them singletons. But you can tell the container to only produce one of each and reuse it. For example, using Castle Windsor:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISomeInterface,SomeClass>));
```

Now every time the container is asked to provide an instance of `ISomeInterface` it will always provide the same instance of `SomeClass`.

Because the dependency you're looking for varies by type (`Dictionary<Type, Something>`) it sounds like what you're looking for might be related to generics. But it would be necessary to take a step back from the smaller problem and understand a slightly larger picture of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Interesting I will have to experiment with this and get back to you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the entire class as static, create a Singleton instance.

```
public class Foo
{
   public static Foo _Foo;
   public Foo()
   {
      _Foo = this;
   }
}
```

Then you may add it to your list, and also inherit from Interfaces, etc.

Comment: I am trying to avoid this as I don't need the object or its state. I just want the function in the dictionary.